# Chatter REST API - Read-By Capability different for different users

Tags: chatter, chatter-rest-api

The `readBy` capability that was introduced in v40.0 is very handy when building custom applications that leverage chatter.  However, non-admin users are not getting the complete capability in the response body (see below) of a feed element.  Administrators are getting a page of items (with the normal chatter rest api pagination) but standard users and community users get `null` for the page.  Is this a setting that I have wrong?

// part of the capability response body

```
readBy: 
{ 
    isReadByMe: true,
    lastReadDateByMe: '2018-01-16T11:20:51.724Z',
    page: null 
},
```

Comment: The page info in the readBy capability is only available for posts that are in private or unlisted groups when the user is non-admin. The page info drives the Seen-by modal on the lightning UI documented here, which contains details on when it is available: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_collab_seenby.htm

Comment: @AlexWu - This is super helpful.  I'm checking the notes in the link you provided against our setup and I will revert back with what I find.  Thanks so much for pointing me to this.

Comment: @AlexWu - What I don't understand is that regular (non-admin) users are not seeing readBy / seen-by information in unlisted Chatter Groups.  They do not have `Hide the Seen By List` checked in their profile.  Not sure why this information is not coming across the API responses.

Comment: if the posts are under unlisted groups and the users do not have `Hide the Seen By List`, then the list should be populated in the readBy capabilities. It is possible that no other users have 'read' the post, therefore the list is empty?

Comment: @AlexWu - These posts have definitely been read.  As an admin I'm getting the `page` populated properly for the same unlisted group / messages.  I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any reason why the page is not properly populated in that case. If you have a test org with the credentials I can play with, I can take a quick look. Otherwise, you might want to work with support to get that resolved.